# How to responsively trim off left and right side of div if screen width is below a specified amount?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am looking to trim the left and right side of a div, let's just say it's a 500px x 500px square div, as you scale the browser in. Essentially it should be trimming this div equally on the left and right side as you scale in the browser in and it should start to occur when the browser is less than 1300px.

```
<div class="trim-my-left-and-right"></div>

.trim-my-left-and-right {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "trim the left and right side". But you can create a responsive width by setting a percentage width based on the width of the `body` tag or other container. You can apply a `min-width` property if you want to keep it above a specific width. However, you may want to investigate browser compatibility of `min-width` and `max-width`.

```
div#container {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:0px;
  max-width:700px;
  margin:0px auto;
  background-color:#AAA;
}

.trim-my-left-and-right {
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color:#000;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ypKp/